# Why do AWS CloudFormation events show no 'status reason' on the console (but work using CLI)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I view events in the console CloudFormation page, I don't see the status reason/details. Like so:
[image: Screenshot of event details from the console. We see the time, the resource, the event type, but no detail.]

I've selected the 'Status reason' in the display config (and the column is showing):
[image]

Bizzarely, it spaces the event elements as if it was going to print the reason/details but it's blank.

However, when I use the CLI, I do see the status reason data.

```bash
 aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name my-stack-name
```

For the same event, we see the `ResourceStatusReason`:
[image]

The 'status reason' was being displayed in the AWS Console last week and I don't think I changed anything that could affect this, so... is this just an AWS bug? Or am I missing some configuration or what?